# Installing expo on command prompt

Tags: reactjs, native, message

I'm trying to install expo in my command prompt after installing node.js but it's telling me that there's a problem related to network connectivity.

Comment: What error are you getting? Please be sure that you follow the instructions correctly: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

*paste this your cmd...... and check  your internet connection *

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```